# Updating a table column based on a join that is made from a union clause

Tags: mysql

I need to update a table historicdata and get some ID's into a new column.  The id's exist in two separate tables, pallets, and pallets_archive.  How can I go about doing this?  I am usin MySQL 6.3.

Here's what I have -

```
UPDATE hd
SET hd.palletIdx = allPallets.idx
FROM historicdata as hd
INNER JOIN (SELECT idx, palletBarcode FROM pallets UNION ALL 
SELECT idx, palletBarcode FROM pallets_archive) as 
allPallets ON hd.palletFullCode = allPallets.palletBarcode
```

But it keeps complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below.

```
UPDATE hd
INNER JOIN (SELECT idx, palletBarcode FROM pallets UNION ALL 
SELECT idx, palletBarcode FROM pallets_archive) as 
allPallets ON hd.palletFullCode = allPallets.palletBarcode
SET hd.palletIdx = allPallets.idx
```